# Generating new polygons based on sum of values

Tags: qgis, clustering, aggregate, values

I am working with QGIS, and I have created the styled density map with the hexagons to calculate pop figures within these. The pop field is displayed inside each polygon.
I now want to create new polygons with a total population of 4000 from the existing hexagon layer.
Is there a way to achieve this?
Please note that I am not working with Python or any other programming language at all.

[image]

Comment: Look for zone design or redistricting